# Is there a way to copy (parts of) a project to another project?

Tags: delphi, ide

I have a large project tree and I decided to set up my tests in a different way. Setting up a new test project is easy but to copy hundreds of files from tens of directories is quite a problem. Is there an easy way to copy all these files from another project tree?

Comment: You don't want to copy files. You want both projects to use the same files.

Comment: I suspect that Saving the project under a new name may help. You can reload the previous one still, but adjust the new one to fit requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not duplicate the files that should be used without change in both test projects, but use separate (sub)folders for the test projects specific files and refer to the common units with a relative path.

Something like:

```
...\MyProject\Test1  and using '..\MyCommonUnit.pas'  
...\MyProject\Test2  and using '..\MyCommonUnit.pas'
```

You do that for the first Test1 project, then merely saving it in another folder with the 'Save Project As' will duplicate the test only files and you can start directly modifying code in the new Test project...

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I wanted. You are right about not duplicating the files. What I had intended to say was that I had to copy the files in the project manager of the IDE. The wording of the the question in misleading though :) Sorry for that.